# Push FormGroup to nested FormArray

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a form where the user can fill out their workout. I'd like call `addSet()` and push a FormGroup to the `sets` FormArray

```js
    ngOnInit() {
       this.workoutForm = new FormArray([
          new FormGroup({
             name: new FormControl(),
             sets: new FormArray([
                new FormGroup({
                   reps: new FormControl(),
                   weight: new FormControl(),
                }),
             ]),
          })
       ]);
    }
    
     public addSet() {
       this.workoutForm.controls[0].controls.sets.push(
          new FormGroup({
             reps: new FormControl(),
             weight: new FormControl(),
          }),
       )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy-paste (By renaming the variables according to your example) from angular docs:

```js
    get sets() {
       return this.workoutForm.get('sets') as FormArray;
    }
    
    addSet(reps, weight) {
       this.sets.push(new FormGroup({
          reps: new FormControl(reps),
          weight: new FormControl(weight),
       }));
    }
```

https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#creating-dynamic-forms